# Find sum of elems in arrays grouped by key

Tags: mongodb

I have the following objects in my collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f39ea016101165e01a40ff"),
"sex" : "Male",
"first_name" : "Andrew",
"last_name" : "Fernandez",
"nationality" : "Somalia",
"credit" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "jcb",
        "number" : "5100178605311200",
        "currency" : "CZK",
        "balance" : "4409.71"
    }
]}
```

The question is: what is the easiest way to count a sum of all balance from every object and group it by currency? As for me, the problem is that credit is an array and there can be many objects in credit array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like it wasn't that difficult for me. I am posting my answer so that anyone in the future can see this post and it might be helpful.

First of all, we need to convert string to float in `credit` objects. To do this, we need to iterate through our collection:

```
db.people.find().forEach( function (x) {   
  x.credit.forEach( function (credit) {
      credit.balance = parseFloat( credit.balance );
  })
  db.people.save(x);
});
```

This will transform our data so that we'll have balance saved as floats. Finally, we need to construct our query:

```
db.people.aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $unwind : "$credit" },
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$credit.currency", 
        restOfMoney: { $sum: '$credit.balance' } 
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

So, what's going on here?

1. Unwind makes extra rows for each item in array
2. Group makes groups based on currency and there we count sum of balance